# JavaFx Remove and Update TableView After Update their row Data

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Hello I am an javaFx Developer and I am working on an Desktop Application I am stuck in problem in which I have to clear and update the TableView from an another Controller I Try to call the clearTable() function which is in an another controller but it is not remove all data from tableview So How I can clear all row from table

First Controller

```
// Add Product Data To Table View From Database    
public void addProductDatabaseFromTableView() {

    try {
        //addProductTable.setItems(data);
        ResultSet resultSet = addNewProductModelObject.getAllProduct();
        while (resultSet.next()) {

            AddProduct addProduct = new AddProduct(resultSet.getString("Product_Code"), resultSet.getString("Product_Name"), resultSet.getInt("Quanlity"), resultSet.getString("Manufactured_date"), resultSet.getString("Expired_date"));
            data.add(addProduct);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AddNewProductController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    System.out.println(data);
}
```

Second Controller

```
public void UpdateProductAction( ActionEvent actionEvent ){
    //System.out.println("UpdateProductAction");
    productModelObject.setProductName(ProductName.getText());
    productModelObject.setProductCode(getProductCode());
    productModelObject.setPrice(Integer.parseInt(RetailPrice.getText()));
    productModelObject.setQuanlity(Integer.parseInt(Quanlity.getText()));
    productModelObject.setManufactureDate(ManuDate.getValue().toString());
    productModelObject.setExpiredDate(ExpDate.getValue().toString());

    boolean checkUpdate = productModelObject.updateProductData();

    if ( checkUpdate ) {
        //System.out.println(checkUpdate);

        //addNewProductController.ClearTableData();
        addNewProductController.addProductDatabaseFromTableView();
        Stage stage = (Stage) BtnClose.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }
}
```

Please Help

Comment: how are you showing those two controllers

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete & Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I think this is useful to you.[passing-parameters-javafx-fxml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml/40193164#40193164)

Comment: zombie kindly check the code

Comment: @CTN thank for your response but its not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `ObservableList` and use the method `setItems(listName);`

Then simple clear all the items from the observable and the changes will be reflected on the Table.

- How i do this?

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm) is a full tutorial

Also [this](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/)  tutorial is a very good start for the next wuestion.

- How to access a controller from another controller?

Use ´MVP´ or ´MVC´ pattern and add instances from one ´Controller´ to another ´Controller´.